# Should my application be decentralized? (Basic Question)

Tags: web3js, ether, metamask, dapps, nft

I know this is a seemingly basic question, but one that I have not found many solid answers to. I have been programming for a few years now and with the recent NFT boom, DApps have caught my interest. But is it worth going through the trouble to launch a decentralized app rather than doing it the traditional way? For example, I want a website that can simply have a couple typical diplay pages. But also has metamask implementation so I can display any NFTs I have purchased on my website. Would an idea like this need to build hosted on the ETH blockchain?

Overall, there has just been the looming question of, "Is a Dapp right for this particular website/project?"

Comment: In additon, I haven't found any documentation that can really answer this question so I am reaching out for people who have experience in this field, BUT if you have documentation you believe will help my understanding, I would love to read it

Comment: Currently it is not possible to host a web page on the Ethereum blockchain. You could use IPFS for storage though.